# Datatool and Siunitx - ERROR: Can't break out of anything

Tags: tables, siunitx, datatool

i'm constantly getting "! Package datatool Error: Can't break out of anything.
" when using data tool and siunitx, if i change the S column definers to normal centered columns (thus not using siunitx) the document compiles correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx} % Provides the \SI{}{} and \si{} command for typesetting SI units
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{datatool}

\sisetup{round-mode=places,
         table-number-alignment = center-decimal-marker
        }


\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{xrfWeight}{masse_xrf.csv}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{r|S[table-format = 1.4]S[table-format = 1.4]S[table-format = 1.4]S[table-format = 1.4]S[table-format = 1.4]}
            \textbf{Mesure} & \textbf{Piece 1} & \textbf{Piece 2} & \textbf{Piece 3} & \textbf{Piece 4} & \textbf{Piece 5}%

            \DTLforeach*{xrfWeight}{\mesure=mesure, \prempiece=prempiece, \deuxpiece=deuxpiece, \troipiece=troipiece, \quatpiece=quatpiece, \cinqpiece=cinqpiece}{%
                \DTLiffirstrow{\\\cmidrule{1-6}}{\\}%
                \mesure & \prempiece & \deuxpiece & \troipiece & \quatpiece & \cinqpiece
            }

        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Poids [g]}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I tried to simplify the table down to only one column with no header (DTL cycle only, with only the \mesure macro) but with no changes...

```
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format = 1.4]|}
        \textbf{Mesure}%

        \DTLforeach*{xrfWeight}{\mesure=mesure, \prempiece=prempiece, \deuxpiece=deuxpiece, \troipiece=troipiece, \quatpiece=quatpiece, \cinqpiece=cinqpiece}{%
            \\%
            \mesure
        }

    \end{tabular}
```

Do you have any clue of what i'm doing wrong?

EDIT -- Added CSV data:

```
mesure,prempiece,deuxpiece,troipiece,quatpiece,cinqpiece
1,2.9955,3.0057,3.0106,2.9693,2.9979
2,2.9951,3.0058,3.0109,2.9699,2.9978
3,2.995,3.0061,3.0108,2.9695,2.9976
4,2.995,3.0061,3.0108,2.9696,2.9977
5,2.9953,3.0057,3.0108,2.9697,2.9978
```

Comment: we of course also need the data for the csv file

Comment: ahaha sorry, added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out the problem, i needed to put

```
@{}l  (or whatever column definer)
```

after the S columns, as well as

```
&
```

after the last row element

Working:

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{r|S[table-format = 1.4]S[table-format = 1.4]S[table-format = 1.4]S[table-format = 1.4]S[table-format = 1.4]@{}l}
            \textbf{Mesure} & \textbf{Piece 1} & \textbf{Piece 2} & \textbf{Piece 3} & \textbf{Piece 4} & \textbf{Piece 5}%

            \DTLforeach*{xrfWeight}{\mesure=mesure, \prempiece=prempiece, \deuxpiece=deuxpiece, \troipiece=troipiece, \quatpiece=quatpiece, \cinqpiece=cinqpiece}{%
                \DTLiffirstrow{\\\cmidrule{1-6}}{\\}%
                \mesure & \prempiece & \deuxpiece & \troipiece & \quatpiece & \cinqpiece &
            }

        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Poids [g]}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```